# How to put the output of a for loop in a column array using Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I am new to Jupyter Notebook. Let's say I have a column of integers (numpy.array) and there is a for loop that goes into each element and adds it to the previous element. I would like to have the output as a column or row of a numpy.array.

I used append operators but the result come in arrays within an array. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Helllo Mansour!, Welcome to stack overflow. Can you please add the code that you tried and and an example output and input. It would be much easier to help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
a=np.arange(10).astype(float)
b=np.array([])
b=np.append(b, a[0])
for sn, i in enumerate(a):
    if sn>0:
        b=np.append(b, a[sn]+a[sn-1])
print(f'a={a}')
print(f'b={b}')
```

Although one can most likely write a more concise code to do the same...